# How to call suspend function from Fragment or Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I want to request permission and do it by nonblocking function. Since I need Context I can not call it from ViewModel. How to give a default UI scope for fragment and call suspend function like this:

```
class MapsFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?

    launch {
         withContext(Dispatcher.Main){
           checkLocationPermission().await()
        }
    }
 }
}


suspend fun checkLocationPermission():Boolean{...}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In documentation https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines said that I can use `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01` ktx.

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        val params = TextViewCompat.getTextMetricsParams(textView)
        val precomputedText = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            PrecomputedTextCompat.create(longTextContent, params)
        }
        TextViewCompat.setPrecomputedText(textView, precomputedText)
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: how about activity?

Comment: You use `lifecycleScope`, an extension property of both activity and fragment (technically extension property of `LifecycleOwner`, which Fragment and Activity implementations implements).

Comment: @roghayehhosseini, you will need to import these two dependencies, **implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1"**
**implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0"**

Answer (score 7):

You can either use

```
GlobalScope.launch {

}
```

or

Make your fragment/activity implement `CoroutineScope`

and set default Dispatcher like this.

```
class Fragment : CoroutineScope {
     
     private val job = Job()
     override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
            get() = job + Dispatchers.Main 

     . . .

     override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        job.cancel()
     }

}
```

Then you can call suspend function like the code you attached in the question.

**Update**

The coroutine scope for activity/fragment can be defined like this.

```
class Fragment : CoroutineScope by MainScope() {
         
        
    ... 
         override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
            cancel()
         }
    
    }
```

Comment: This approach is now outdated, you should let the library take care of it:  `class Fragment : CoroutineScope by MainScope {`. It will use the proper `SupervisorJob` instead of a plain `Job`. See the docs on [CoroutineScope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/), you must still override the destroy callback: `override fun onDestroy() { cancel() }`

Comment: @Boonya Kitpitak shouldn't we call cancel in `onDestroyView()` instead of `onDestroy()` since a Fragment could be retained and it could have references to views in the coroutine?

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
suspend fun foundError() {
coroutineScope {
    async { 
        throw StructuredConcurrencyWill("throw")
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can return a `MutableLiveData` from the function and wait for the coroutine to work and return back.

```
fun fetchDocuments(): MutableLiveData<TodoResponseModel> {
    val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<TodoResponseModel>()
    Log.d("COROUTINE", "Main Context started")
    GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Main) {
        Log.d("COROUTINE", "IO Context started")
        val response = repository.getTodoCoroutineFourth()
        Log.d("COROUTINE", "IO Context completed")
        mutableLiveData.value = response.body()
        Log.d("COROUTINE", "IO Context finished")
    }
    Log.d("COROUTINE", "Main Context ended")
    return mutableLiveData
}
```