# How to start a coroutine on main thread without using GlobalScope?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Whenever I want to start a coroutine on a main thread,

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        suspededFunction()
    }
}

suspend fun suspededFunction() {
    delay(5000L) //heavy operation
}
```

GlobalScope is highlighted, and always taunt that its usage is delicate and require care.

What delicacies are involved with GlobalScope, and importantly how can I start a coroutine without using GlobalScope?

Comment: You can create your Own Scope . infact there is already scope Available for some classes . Inside viewModel you can directly use `viewModelScope` and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59043638/how-to-call-suspend-function-from-fragment-or-activity) for Activity or fragment .

Comment: thanks @ADM it was helpful. I devised an answer from it as well. just for the reference. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start coroutine without using a GlobalScope, one can do as:

```
val job = Job()
val scope = CoroutineScope(job)

scope.launch {
        suspededFunction()
    }
```

As mentioned in comments, some classes already have scopes available, like `ViewModel` class as `viewModelScope`.

in Activity or Fragment you can as follows:

```
//not recommended to use co-routines inside fragment or activity class
// this is just for example sack shown here.
// otherwise you have to do all your processing inside viewmodel
    class Fragment : CoroutineScope by MainScope() {
             
            
        ... 
             override fun onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy()
                cancel()
             }
        
        }
```

Comment: Don’t do that in a fragment. They already have `lifecycleScope` and `viewLifecycle.lifecycleScope`. The examples you may have seen that do that are from before the Jetpack libraries provided proper coroutine scopes.

Comment: this is just an example, that it can be done. now included in the answer as well. thanks for pointing out. @Tenfour04

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin already created some scope. you can use it according to your situation. and you also create your own scope. but I suggest in the beginning it is better to use that already created
check official documentation https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(viewBinding.root)

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        //for activity
    }


}



  //for viewmodel
suspend fun abc() = viewModelScope.launch { 
     
    }
```